# Is there a normal range of database calls in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a Ruby on Rails app and it displays a list of programs. Each of those programs has a like/unlike button, so there is a database query for each program on whether or not a User Likes the program or not. This creates 20 database calls (displays per page). Is this normal?

I realize I can cache those based on whether the program is liked by any user, but ignoring the cache, is that a pretty normal thing for a page or have I programmed it terribly?

Comment: well - i wouldn't say it's abnormal.. you can always optimize the code to return all the likes at once, then iterate through, and display them in order

Comment: It is a programs index page and it needs to determine if each specific program that is returned (which can be any, as there is a search feature) is liked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a "user" has_many "programs" through "user_programs":

controller -

```
@user_programs = User.find(id).user_programs
```

view -

```
<% @user_programs do |user_program| %>
  <%= user_program.liked %>
<% end %>
```

If you need "program" information too, add :include when getting your collection

```
@user_programs = User.find(id).user_programs(:include => :program)
```

If you are searching and can return any program even if it is not connected to the current user then you will have to query on programs and use a join to get current user information:

```
@programs = Program.joins("LEFT JOIN user_programs ON user_programs.program_id = programs.id").where("user_programs.user_id = ? AND programs.name =?", current_user.id,params[:q])
```

Comment: My apologies, I just meant it displays a list of programs (created by users), not necessarily user programs. So the programs could come from any user and are usually a result of a search.

Comment: In that case the last example with the join would probably be your best bet to join the search results with the current users preferences.